# Progress bar первоначальной загрузки

Tags: android, progress-bar

Подскажите, с помощью чего можно сделать такой прогресс бар.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это стандартный `ProgressDialog`. Пример:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Идет поиск рейсов");
progressDialog.show();
```

Для отмены:

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Можете обвешать чем необходимо:

```
.setCancelable(false); //не закрывается по тапу вокруг
.setTitle("Title"); //Заголовок
```

И много другого, подробно в [официальной документации](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

Answer (score 2):

`AsyncTask` c `progressdialog`'ом

**Пример:**

```
private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>{
            private ProgressDialog nDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                super.onPreExecute();
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);
                nDialog.setTitle("");
                nDialog.setMessage("");
                nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                nDialog.setCancelable(false);
                nDialog.show();
            }
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){
                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL("https://www.google.ru/");
                        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                        urlc.connect();
                        if(urlc.getResponseCode() == 200){
                            return true;
                        }
                    }catch(MalformedURLException e1){
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }catch(IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){
                if(th == true){
                    nDialog.dismiss();
                    new Process().execute();
                }
                else{
                    nDialog.dismiss();
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    ErrorMsg.setText("");
                }
            }
        }
```